# No Sound in ubuntu 18.04 ASUS R558U

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio

Output of `sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` is

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ef128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at ef100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Also I am unable to install `alsamixer`.
Throws error

```
E: Unable to locate package alsamixer
```

I have tried various solutions. But to no use. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot locate the package alsamixer is because it actually doesn't exist. You have to install the `alsa-utils` package to get alsamixer. Or, you can install and use `pulseaudio` instead as a replacement for alsamixer.

Comment: alsa-utils is already installed. And pulseaudio is also installed.